# Flow Diagram creation using vis.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vis.js

I want to create flow diagram with drag and drop functionality. Is `vis.js` suitable for that functionality as showing in this [example](https://github.com/woodenconsulting/react-js-diagrams/blob/master/images/main.png)
Or there are other open source libraries are available which is based on node js.
suggest me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Vis.js is a great tool, if you what to build something not that complex in no time. 
Another great library is [D3.js](https://d3js.org/). There is a big community around it. But for the functionality you want [D3.js](https://d3js.org/). I highly recommend their docummentation.